# Check if data exists in database

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a login system using c#. I want to check if the username the user enters is already part of the database. This is the code that connects to a data adapter and then updates this once I have taken the data from the check boxes.

```
NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter north = new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersDataTable northtable = north.GetData();


NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet1 = new NorthwindDataSet();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow newCustomersRow =
northwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow();

newCustomersRow.Username = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
newCustomersRow.Password = TextBox2.Text.ToString() ;
newCustomersRow.FirstName = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
newCustomersRow.Surname = TextBox4.Text.ToString();

northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);

north.Update(northwindDataSet1.Customers);
northwindDataSet1.Customers.AcceptChanges();

if (Page.IsValid)
 Response.Redirect("thankyou.aspx");
```

What is the best way to check the `Username` field for duplicate data?

Answer (score 3):

Call me crazy, but I'd just do something like (using "dapper")

```
string username = ...
int existingId = connection.Query<int?>(
    @"select top 1 Id from Users where UserName = @username",
     new { username }).FirstOrDefault();
 if(existingId.HasValue) {
       // not available - do something
 }
```

Note that there is a race condition here so you should still have a unique constraint on the column itself. You might also want to thing about case sensitivity: is "Fred" the same username as "fred"?

Comment: This is correct, we can check if the username is duplicated in the table.

Comment: @Joshua a data access tool that makes it really really easy and efficient to work with SQL and objects without big complex ORM or adapters getting in the way. Just Google "dapper" to find it - or look on nuget if you have vs2012. It is what stackoverflow.com wrote to do all their data access.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to mark the table Column as primary key or unique? Then you handle the exception inside a try{}catcht{} statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `DataTable.Select`? Something like:

```
var UserFound = NorthTable.Select("UserName = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'");
if(UserFound.Length != 0)
{
    // do something...
}
```